# I am trying to redirect to remove specific part from url using .htaccess but its not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

I am trying to remove this leads from this url:
http://localhost:8000/leads/all_leads
so that when a user comes to this url, he is redirected to this url:
http://localhost:8000/all_leads
Means i want to remove the /leads from url
i have tried using htaccess but its not working.

Here is the code of my .htaccess

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Remove "leads" prefix from URLs
    RewriteRule ^leads/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This line of code below is also uncommented in httpd.conf file in apache
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
and

```
<Directory>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I have also tried by commenting Require all denied but still no progress

Comment: RewriteRule ^leads/all_leads$ /all_leads [L,R=301] can you try that?

Comment: just tried it, no progress. I tried to check if htaccess is working fine by adding random text but i am not seeing any error. 
```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Remove "leads" prefix from URLs
    RewriteRule ^leads/all_leads$ /all_leads [L,R=301]
    asdfasdf
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have to use `Route::redirect` all the way, even if you have 1000 routes, do not modify the `.htaccess`...

Answer (score 1):

You should not be changing the .htaccess, instead create a redirect in your router:

```php
Route::redirect('/leads/all_leads', '/all_leads');
```

Comment: Its not only 1 route, this is only for example, there are multiple routes like all_leads, edit, delete, and much more even

Comment: why do you have such routes?